# Labview: displaying few curves on one Waveform Chart

Tags: charts, labview, waveform

I'd like to display few curves on one Waveform Chart. Theoretically, I know how to do it (i.e. http://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/how-do-i-display-multiple-plots-on-one-chart/td-p/803352).

But I got an error which says that the source is a cluster of (let's say) 9 elements and the sink is a double.

Shouldn't Labview be intelligent enough to figure out that I want to display 9 curves, not one? How can I change the settings of the Waveform Chart to inform Labview that I want to display 9 curves?

I'm sure I don't use the Waveform Chart in any other part of my code (I created a new chart to test it and I got the same error again).

Here is my code (without an error, but in fact, I don't know why). When I tried to do the same for 9 curves, I got the error.

[image]

Comment: What is the data type of the 9 elements you are describing?

Comment: Each of the elements is a double, but I create a waveform of ot using the build in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change bundle function with build array

[image]